# Crear un select dinamico en laravel 5.7 (pais - ciudad)

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, select

hola esoty recien empezando con laravel tengo dos tablas pais y ciudad relacionada correctamente, quiero crear un select en mi formulario que el seleccionar el pais me muestre las ciudades que tiene asociadas en otro select.

muchas gracias

Comment: la forma mas simple es desplegar los paises en el select usando un foreach y agregar js usando ajax para que cuando cambie el select llame una url que traiga los datos de las ciudades.